# How to create custom calendar in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile

I need to create custom calendars in React Native.  I have attached some screenshots below.

The first one is a square calendar and the second one is a horizontal flatList.

Can any one of you please suggest how you would have proceeded if this was your project?

[image]

[image]

Thanks and Kind Regards,
Avinash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways to make your custom calendar

1. You can download libraries[not install] and then edit their code to make your own library and add it to your component.(preferred way)
2. Or you can make your layout for days, weeks , months, etc and use scroll-view to make it swipe-able. Most of libraries also uses scroll-view.

Comment: I know that using existing libs is the way to go but I wondered if there were any other options out there.

Comment: I think you miss understood me. I am not suggesting you to use existing libs. I am saying you can download and modify their styles in their code.
for eg 
this is library
https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars
and this modified library
https://github.com/eals/react-native-calender-pn-wix-extended

Comment: I will use your suggestion as well :)

Answer (score 1):

I created a calendar strip component that support swipe to change week.

Using horizontal FlatList, lazy load date on week change.

And support **go today**, **swipe down gesture callback**, and so on.

https://github.com/FaiChou/react-native-slideable-calendar-strip

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `react-native-calendar-strip`. I've used it several times and it is quite usable.

Here is how I impelemeted it.

```
<CalendarStrip
                            calendarAnimation={{type: 'sequence', duration: 30}}
                            daySelectionAnimation={{type: 'border', duration: 200, borderWidth: 1, borderHighlightColor: 'white'}}
                            style={{height: 80, paddingTop: 20, paddingBottom: 10, marginBottom: 15}}
                            calendarHeaderStyle={{color: 'white'}}
                            calendarColor={'#7743CE'}
                            dateNumberStyle={{color: 'white'}}
                            dateNameStyle={{color: 'white'}}
                            highlightDateNumberStyle={{color: 'yellow'}}
                            highlightDateNameStyle={{color: 'yellow'}}
                            disabledDateNameStyle={{color: 'grey'}}
                            disabledDateNumberStyle={{color: 'grey'}}
                            onDateSelected={(date)=>this.dateSelected(date)}
                            datesWhitelist={datesWhitelist}
                        />
```

And here is how it looks.

[image]

Comment: sorry to be harsh, but you didn't implemented that, that's the example from the calendar strip github